# Error deleting select options in internet explorer 8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, getjson

Its working in Firefox but in Internet Explorer the select(dropdown) just hide from the page when getJSON return from action. This is my code

```
  $.getJSON("/Post/GetResourcetype", {}, function (data1) {
            $($("#ddResourcetype").attr("options"), $("#ddResourcetype")).remove();            
            $.each(data1, function (key, value) {                
                var arrkey = new Array();
                arrkey = key.toString().split('_');
                $('#ddResourcetype').append('<option value="' + value + '" name="' + arrkey[1] + '">' + arrkey[1] + '</object>');
            });
        });
```

what is the issue in following code.

When i comment $($("#ddResourcetype").attr("options"), $("#ddResourcetype")).remove();

It works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I change this line of code

```
$($("#Parent").attr("options"), $("#Parent")).remove();
```

to

```
 $("#Parent").empty();
```

For deleting previous value of select and now its working fine in both browsers

Answer (score 0):

at the end of object instead of option

```
$('#ddResourcetype').append('<option value="' + value + '" name="' + arrkey[1] + '">' + arrkey[1] + '</object>');
```

it should be

> ```
> $('#ddResourcetype').append('<option value="' + value + '" name="' + arrkey[1] + '">' + arrkey[1] + '</option>');
> ```